# Why Can't I Read String Resources from a Service in Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-resources

So I'm pretty sure this a problem with `Context` and I know there are a lot of related questions out there (I've read them) but nothing I could find matched my specific case so hoping someone can help.  **I am building against API 28, min 24, language level 7 and running on an Android 7 Samsung tablet.**

#### Situtation

In my project I have a `Service` that is intended to start on device boot, and it does. In order to verify this for myself, I had the Service issue a notification. Once I got it working I cleaned up the code and moved all the titles, names, and such into string resources in the `strings.xml` file.

#### Problem

The notification no longer appears. If I use hardcoded strings, everything is fine, if I try to use string resources the notification fails. My guess is that this has something to do with the `Context` (from which strings are requested) and it not having access to them. However, in the hardcoded strings case an icon resource (drawable) and a color resource are both queried successfully, so I'm unclear on what the difference is with strings. I could just hardcode the strings and call it a day but I feel that goes against Android best practices. I should also note that everything is fine with the resources if I actually launch the app, this is only a problem in the "on boot" condition.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

#### As requested: the code

This works:

```
public static void notify(Context context, String text){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "CHANNEL",
                "My App",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("Service status update channel");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder n  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL")
            .setContentTitle("Status")
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.notify(notification_id, n.build());
}
```

This does not:

```
public static void notify(Context context, String text){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                context.getString(R.string.notification_channel),
                context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription(context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_desc));
        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder n  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.notification_channel))
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.notify(notification_id, n.build());
}
```

I call this method from the `Service`'s `onStartCommand`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    UIHelper.notify(getApplicationContext(), "hello");
    return IntentService.START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Pass `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: And use `context.getResources().getString()` instead of just `context.getString()`

Comment: OK that worked.  Can you make a formal answer so I can mark it correct. And could you also provide some clarification about what the difference in those calls are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your call to `getApplicationContext()` with `this`:

```
UIHelper.notify(this, "hello");
```

Also, use `context.getResources().getString()` instead of just `context.getString()`.

Unfortunately, I don't really have an explanation for why it's like this.

My thoughts are that you're making a foreground Service, so the notification for that Service should belong to the Service itself (which extends Context) and not the Application.

In theory, `context.getString()` is exactly the same as `context.getResources().getString()` (it's actually just a proxy method), although it was only introduced in Marshmallow.